# Losing precision after parsing an integer

Tags: javascript, integer

I countered this issue in my program, I have a string `numStr` and I want to parse it as an `integer`.

I tried both on `node` and `spider-monkey` environments.

What is the problem and how I fix it?

```
const numStr = '12360600901222567';
console.log(+numStr);
console.log(parseInt(numStr));
console.log(parseFloat(numStr));
console.log(Number(numStr));
```

Output:

```
12360600901222568
12360600901222568
12360600901222568
12360600901222568
```

Expected:

```
12360600901222567
```

Comment: `12360600901222568` is greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` - though, in node (and Chrome) there is `BigInt('12360600901222567')`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin